# Why does this code in my callback execute on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Javascript:

```
$('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination({
    totalPages: 35,
    visiblePages: 7,
    onPageClick: function (event, page) {
        console.log('Why does this run on load?');
    }
});
```

Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/js/jquery.twbsPagination.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="pagination-demo" class="pagination-sm"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

JS Bin here: http://jsbin.com/potekina/1/edit

In the onPageClick callback I log to the console "Why does this run on load?" I dont understand why that code is running on load if its only supposed to happen when links are clicked. Why does it run on load?

Comment: JSBin is great as a supplement, but please add all relevant code here too, just in case JSBin doesn't exist in the future :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the source](http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/js/jquery.twbsPagination.js):

```
init: function (options) {
   ...
   this.$element.bind('page', this.options.onPageClick);
   ...
   this.$element.trigger('page', this.options.startPage);
}
```

The twpsPagination plugin is apparently triggering `onPageClick` in init. It's a peculiarity of the plugin, not an anomaly in your code. We can't give an answer to what the authors' reasoning behing that design choice was.

Presumably, the event was intended for post page-render setup, and they've guessed that it's just as relevant for setting up the initial page as for subsequent page loads, but I'll give you that "page click" is a bit of a misnomer then.

If you really want to have your scripts run only on actual page clicks, you'd have to perform some workaround, such as a variable:

```
var firstPageClick = true;

onPageClick: function() {
   if(firstPageClick) {
       firstPageClick = false;
       return;
   }

   // actual event listener
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Here I was thinking my entire understanding of javascript was fundamentally wrong again.

Answer (score 13):

There is an option to add in init :

```
$('.pagination').twbsPagination({
    initiateStartPageClick: false
});
```